# Sequelize: Update database schema

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In Sequelize I have the following model file: collection.js

```
  'use strict';
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
      var Collection = sequelize.define('Collection', {
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        bundleSize: DataTypes.INTEGER
      }, {
        classMethods: {
          associate: function(models) {
            Collection.belongsTo(models.User, {
              onDelete: 'CASCADE',
              foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false,
              }
            })

          }
        }
      });
      return Collection;
    };
```

I'm using the express example provided by Sequelize on github.

I created it via sequelize-cli, and then added manually the relationship. But now I can't get the foreign key to be created. I'm using Sync with force equals true. But all I can get is the table with all it's fields, but without the association(foreign key).
Is there a way to update the database schema based on the models files? Or I will have to manually edit a migration file and then run a migration?

Comment: What version of Sequelize are you on

Comment: Take a look [at the fine manual](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto) on how to declare relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreignKey will be created automatically if don't provide the foreignKey property in the association options. It will consist the mother table name and 'Id' suffix. In your case, it will the field 'UserId' in the 'Collections' table

Collection.belongsTo(models.User, {
              onDelete: 'CASCADE'
            })

If you want to provide custom foreign key it should be either STRING or options object with a field property in it, with would be the name of the column in the table.

```
Collection.belongsTo(models.User, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE'
          foreignKey: 'myCustomUserId'
        })
```

I'm not sure how to alias properly the foreignKey table field name to in app sequelize. It is possible that the following would be enough

```
 User.hasMany(models.Collection, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'myCustomForeignKey',
            field: 'my_custom_foreign_key'
          }
        })
 Collection.belongsTo(models.User, {
          onDelete: 'CASCADE',
          foreignKey: {
            name: 'myCustomForeignKey',
            field: 'my_custom_foreign_key'
          }
        })
```

It will create automatic in-app alias 'myCustomForeignKey' along with table column 'my_custom_foreign_key

So the following queries should give the same results :

```
db.Collection.findAll({where: {myCustomForeignKey: 22}})
```

`sequelize.query('select * from collections where my_custom_foreign_key=22')`